# HTML: How can I put a vertical line between horizontally ordered elements?

Tags: html, css

So I was searching for a HTML code like: &middot (which makes a dot) but for a vertical line.
I was firstly using a border at the left and right, but then I had thick lines in the middle and normal lines on the outside. If someone could give me a list with all the '&' codes that would be great! I'm a beginner at using HTML and CSS, but willing to learn!
(btw, I need such a line because I am creating a menu. I need to put the line inbetween the Menu elements.)

Comment: What  code you you have already?

Comment: `'If someone could give me a list with all the '&' codes that would be great!'` - Lists like that already exist on the internet. But you don't need codes, such a line is probably on your keyboard. Here it is: `|`

Comment: Vertical bar is `&#124;`

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is give every element a right border, and give the first child an additional left border.

```
.div {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.div:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

`&` codes are for *content* and shouldn't be used for presentational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If the divide should only appear *between* the elements and not on the ends, this will work:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/jdt9afa4

```
.element + .element {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The "& codes" are called, in HTML5, "[character references](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#character-references)". There are "named character references" and "numeric character references".

Numeric character references can address any [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) character.

Named character references only cover a very small subset of those, but a full and authoritative list can be found here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#named-character-references

However. you should probably follow nullability's advice.